# HTML5 Audio live stream gives connection refused in device

Tags: html, angular, audio, ionic2, ionic3

The MP3 live audio stream in our Ionic 3 app works correctly with `ionic serve`, but running it on a device it gives `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on Android and `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100` on iOS.

**My player service:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {
    stream: any;
    promise: any;

    constructor() {
        this.initLiveStream();
    }

    initLiveStream() {
        this.stream = new Audio('http://audio-mp3.ibiblio.org:8000/wcpe.mp3');
    }

    play() {
        this.stream.play();

        this.promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            this.stream.addEventListener('playing', () => {
                resolve(true);
            });

            this.stream.addEventListener('error', () => {
                reject(false);
            });
        });

        return this.promise;
    };

    pause() {
        this.stream.pause();
    };
}
```

Replacing the live stream URL with an URL to a MP3 file (e.g. https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3) works. Probably the problem has something to do with the live stream having no length, but I can't figure out how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [**Native Streaming Media Plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/) here. Since some of the web solutions are not working properly on native devices.

> This plugin allows you to stream audio and video in a fullscreen,
>   native player on iOS and Android.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-streaming-media
npm install --save @ionic-native/streaming-media
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the native player, but it completely blocks the functionality of my app as it is full screen. But more important: the mp3 file plays, but the live stream gives `Media Player Error: Unknown (1) -1005`

Comment: Above error comes when you played the live stream on the native player(plugin)?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I just found out the problem has something to do with the stream and not the app. I tried the stream of a very popular Radio Station in the Netherlands (http://icecast.omroep.nl/3fm-bb-mp3) and it works on above code (even with HTML5 solution).
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh.. Ok great :)